# How to resolve error "SQL0104N" when running "db2 prune logfile prior to" command?

Tags: db2, scripting, db2-luw, unix

I wrote an script to delete transaction log files in db2. I need to delete all the files prior to the active log file.I wrote this code as .sh file

```
db2 connect to DWHDB
db2 get db cfg | grep '/tlogdir/DWHDB/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000'
db2 get db cfg | grep "First active log file">sample.txt
x= awk '{print substr($0,60,12)}' sample.txt
db2 prune logfile prior to $x
```

When I execute above code following error came

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "TO".
Expected tokens may include:  "<identifier>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: if you `echo $x` after line 4, what does it say? I suspect you actually want to do: `x=\`awk '{print substr($0,60,12)}' sample.txt\``

Comment: Your x= statement is wrong. You can do something like: `x=$(db2 get db cfg for sample | grep "First Active log file" | cut -f2 -d=)`. You can also test whether x got value before pruning: `if [ -z $x ]; then echo "Unable to determine logfile"; exit 1; fi`

Comment: I vote to reopen the question, the question concerns a pretty common task among Db2 Administrators (though the error is likely due to misunderstanding of how sh works)

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of:

```
db2 get db cfg | grep '/tlogdir/DWHDB/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000'
```

?

Futhermore, your statement:

```
x= awk '{print substr($0,60,12)}' sample.txt
```

is wrong. I'm not sure what it might mean, I get a syntax error trying. You need to use `Command Substitution` like:

```
x=$(awk ...)
```

or the older backtick version (above is recommended)

However, instead of redirecting to a file, I would suggest something like:

```
x=$(db2 get db cfg for sample | grep "First Active log file" | cut -f2 -d=)
```

`cut` is likely to be more stable over db2 versions than `awk substr(...` (number of positions in LOGFILE may be increased in the future)

All and all you can do something like:

```
db2 connect to DWHDB
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

x=$(db2 get db cfg | grep "First Active log file" | cut -f2 -d=)
if [ -z $x ]; then 
    echo "Unable to determine logfile"; 
    exit 1; 
fi
db2 prune logfile prior to $x
```